# Jackson Custom String to Date Serializer

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, jackson

I am trying to make Jackson to parse String to Date with given format. I came up with the following code for now:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EventData implements Serializable {

    private transient SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @JsonSerialize(using = StringToDateSerializer.class, as = Date.class)
    private Date eventStart;

    public class StringToDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(String tmpString,
                              JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            try {                
                jsonGenerator.writeObject(formatter.parse(tmpString));
            } catch (ParseException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my only field eventStart always get populated with NULL. Also, it does not stops on breakpoint inside try/catch block as if it is never been invoked. The other (non custom) fields are populated fine.
What I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you more detail on how you are using this EventData ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert JSON into EventData where one of the fields is a data string then you need to deserialize it (serialization is process when you convert your Java object into the JSON/stream of bytes).

Jackson provide better way how to handle Date format:

```
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling
```

Since Jackson 2.0 you can use JsonFormat where you can specify custom date format

```
  public class DateStuff {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd,HH:00", timezone="CET")
    public Date creationTime;
  }
```